# Logging new connections in a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, network-programming, linux-containers

How to log new connections inside a docker container? In a normal VM or physical machines, we can make use of iptables logging, but in a docker container, the kernel logs cant be seen. So commands like these wont work:

```
`iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix ' OUTBOUND: ' --log-level 1`
```

I am trying to make use of `ss` in linux to capture new connections, but cant find the right filter. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: syn-sent( ss -nt state syn-sent ) filter with `ss` seems to find new connections, but still looking for better solution